# parallel computing combination_with_replacement using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to get the all possible combination with replacement and make with each of them some calculation. I'm using the code below:

```
from itertools import combination_with_replacement

for seq in combination_with_replacement('ABCDE', 500):
    # some calculation
```

How can I parallelize this calculation using multiprocessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard library [`concurrent.futures`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def processing(combination):
    print(combination)
    # Compute interesting stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
    result = executor.map(processing, combinations_with_replacement('ABCDE', 25))
    for r in result:
         # do stuff ...
```

A bit more explanations:

- This code creates an executor using `processes`. Another possibility would be to use `threads` but full python threads only run on one core so it might not be the solution of interest in your case as you need to run heavy computation.
- The map object return a asynchronous object. Thus, the line `executor.map..` is non blocking and you can do other computation before collecting the result in the `for` loop.
- It is important to declare the `processing` function out of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and to declare and use the executor in this block. This prevent for infinite executor spawning and permit to `pickle` the worker function to pass it to the child process. Without this block, the code is likely to fail.

I recommend this over `multiprocessing.Pool` as it has a more clever way to dispatch the work as you are using an iterator.

Note that your computation for combination of `500` with 5 elements `ABCDE` might not be possible. It needs to compute `5**500 > 1e350` elements. By parallelizing, you will only reduce your computation linearly by a factor `max_workers`, so in this case `8` and each process will need to run with `~ 1e349` elements, which should take about `~ 1e335` years if each computation is done in 1 micro second.